# How to set option value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, selection

Following is my code for repeat options set in a **controller** -

```
$scope.repeats = [
    {name: "No", value: 3},
    {name: "Every day", value: 6},
    {name: "Every week", value: 9},
    {name: "Every month", value: 12},
    {name: "Every year", value: 15},
];
```

Following is the code in the **HTML** template for creating select options -

```
<select id="repeatval" 
        ng-model="event.repeat" 
        ng-options="repeat.value as repeat.name for repeat in repeats"
        ng-init="event.repeat = event.repeat || repeats[0].value" 
        class="btn">
</select>
```

Following is the generated code -

```
<select class="btn ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-init="event.repeat = event.repeat || repeats[0].value" ng-options="repeat.value as repeat.name for repeat in repeats" ng-model="event.repeat" id="repeatval">
<option value="0">No</option>
<option value="1">Every day</option>
<option value="2">Every week</option>
<option value="3">Every month</option>
<option value="4">Every year</option>
</select>
```

Now as you can see, that values are coming as `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` though my expectation was  - `3, 6, 9, 12, 15`

Let me know what I am doing wrong and wrong about the concept here.

FYI - If I am consoling `console.log(event.repeat);` I am getting the correct values 3, 6 etc

Please let me know what I am doing wrong with the concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, this is how `ng-options` works. It assigns a `value` attribute to each `<option>` that is the index of the option in the array. Then when the select's `change` event occurs, it looks up the object at that index in the array, evaluates the value expression (`event.value` in your case) and sets the `ng-model`'s value accordingly.

This should not be important to you if you are doing things *the AngularJS way*, because almost everything will be accessing the *model* (scope), not the DOM.

However, if you must set the `value` attribute correctly for your `<option>` tags, don't use `ng-options` and use the following markup instead:

```
<select id="repeatval" 
        ng-model="event.repeat" 
        ng-init="event.repeat = event.repeat || repeats[0].value" 
        class="btn">
        <option ng-repeat="repeat in repeats track by repeat.value" value="{{repeat.value}}">
            {{repeat.name}}
        </option>
</select>
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/B8gAw8soVU7paD9MaOXa?p=preview)

Comment: I am not using `ng-repeat` as at places I read that to avoid its usage due to performance impact as I have around 5-6 select on my form page..+1 for `This should not be important to you if you are doing things the AngularJS way, because almost everything will be accessing the model (scope), not the DOM`